# does android 1.5 saves fpu regs on context switch

Tags: android

i'm asking 1.5 and up

or is it dependant on what's in ".config" when compiled for my phone?

(and yes, i know that android has to support processors with soft-float, but several libm on different phones do have hard-float libm)

(please provide -if possible- any link to/file name of context switching function for msm 7200A/7201A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they weren't saved on context switch, then the floating-point hardware would (essentially) be completely useless.  I believe that Android supports using hardware FP on processors that have it (can someone who knows confirm this?) -- assuming that is correct, those registers must be saved on a context switch.

Answer (score 0):

no a direct answer, but I think the MSM 7200A doesn't have a FPU.

also agree with Stephen's answer that it is quiet reasonable to expect the OS deals with preserving the fpu regs across context switches.  do you have reason to believe it doesn't?